# IndexedDB - multiple items for an id

Tags: indexeddb

I'm trying to build an IndexedDB application that uses the following (one-to-many key value pair, i.e. each id has multiple images) data structure:

`var images = [{"id": "1", "img":["img1","img2","img3"]},
               {"id": "1", "img":["img4","img5","img6"]}]`

My question is how do I put and get using this structure. All the examples out there either iterate through all the keys or have a single value associated with each key that they can easily get. Can I open a cursor on the get('id') method and iterate through all the "img" items for that id? 
Here's what I have currently tried:

1) Getting for a specific key(one-to-one mapping):

```
var dbGet = function(id, cbGet){             
    var transaction = db.transaction(["images"],"readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("images");
    var request = objectStore.get(id);
    request.onerror = function(event) {};
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {         
    if(typeof(e.target.result) != "undefined"){             
            cbGet(null,null,e.target.result);
         }          
    };  
};
```

2) Getting for all the keys:

```
var dbGetAll = function(id){
    var transaction = db.transaction(["images"],"readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("images");
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
      if (cursor) {
        //Do something
        cursor.continue();
      }      
    };
}
```

3) How to get 'all' for a specific key (one-to-many mapping)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself, posting it here for others who might be struggling with this:

1) Get an existing array of values for the given key:

```
function getExisting(id, object){
    var existingImgArr = new Array();
    var transaction = db.transaction(["images"],"readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("images");
    var request = objectStore.get(id);
    request.onerror = function(event) {

    };
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {                   
        if(typeof(e.target.result) != "undefined"){ 
            existingImgArr = (e.target.result.img);            
        }           
        dbSaveWithExisting(id, object,existingImgArr);
    };
```

2) Second, on the success callback of the above, call another function to append to the existing array of vals:

```
function appendToExisting(id, object, imgArr){
    var transaction = db.transaction(["images"], "readwrite");      

    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {};
    transaction.onerror = function(event) {};

    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("images");
    imgArr.push(object.value);
    var data = {"id": id, 
            "img": imgArr
    };  
    var request = objectStore.put(data);
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {};     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a single object store (images)
- Use an auto-incrementing unique id (guid)
- Store a property representing the id for grouped items (itemid)
- Create an index on itemid (non-unique)
- Open a cursor on a specific itemid with IDBKeyRange.exact (or whatever it is i forget)
- Iterate over the cursor to get a group of items with the same id